# Can uefi applications make calls to DXE lib api's and vice versa

Tags: uefi

I am working in edk2 Tianocore. I have written a DXE driver for some data processing, this driver is automatically executed just before BDS phase.
I have also written an uefi Application for doing the same job, this app. can be executed from uefi shell by user.

The common code for the Dxe driver and application is put in a uefi Library. The problem is the Print () function calls in the Library are not working when called from Dxe driver, they are working well when called from app.

Answer (score 2):

The Print function will not work until the output console is initialized in the BDS phase, at which point the gST->ConOut pointer is populated. You can replace the Print calls in your library with your own function, e.g. PrintApp, which internally will check gST->ConOut, and only call Print when gST->ConOut is not NULL. During development I also like calling DEBUG (...) in DXE and Print (...) after ReadyToBoot in the PrintApp function, so I see the same messages going out to either debug console or the screen.